# Issue installing Windows 10 on Samsung 950 Pro M.2 SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios, m.2

I recently purchased a brand new PC which I have just finished building. The specs are as follows:

- Corsair 750D Case
- GPU: EVGA Classified 4-way motherboard
- RAM: 16GB (2x8GB) G.Skill Trident Z 3200MHz
- CPU: i7 6700k
- HDD: 2TB WD for storage
- SSD: 512GB Samsung 950 Pro M.2 SSD
- Corsair H115i GT AIO Liquid Cooler
- PSU: Corsair HX850i Power Supply

I am trying to install Windows 10 Pro via a USB. On first boot it was no problem I successfully entered the BIOS enabled the M.2 socket on my motherboard for my Samsung 950 SSD, and set the USB as the boot priority so that I could install Windows 10. Upon restarting the computer to install my OS, I am met with a black screen with a blinking underscore in the top left corner.

I turned off the machine and removed the 950 pro SSD and it successfully booted off the USB and the installation wizard came up with no issue. I then shutdown the machine and reinstalled the 950 pro M.2 SSD, and once again I get the black screen with a blinking underscore. Note that the first screen that i see is the black screen and blinking underscore, I do not even get to see the BIOS splash screen, nor am I able to enter the BIOS when I have the M.2 SSD installed on my motherboard.

Comment: [Driver](https://mega.nz/#!BMkTTIYT!eGkmAYmjIHjtFChQ635ySy1P1f5MA9w2u_sXyIM9TBw) <----Here is the driver you will need once installed. Also what guielines did you follow install here is a nice post right [Here](https://tinkertry.com/how-to-boot-win10-from-samsung-950-pro-nvme-on-superserver)

Comment: @NetworkKingPin I cannot install. Having the m.2 ssd in my motherboard causes a black screen and a blinking cursor, so i cannot proceed and or anything.

Comment: Have you tried Migrating your os to the SSD? Using the [Magician Software](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html) These M2 ssds seem to be tricky I have yet to play with one yet but may try and purchase one here soon.

Comment: Since you specifically have Samsung 950 Pro (which is NVMe not standard SATA) - try some guide that people have made https://tinkertry.com/how-to-boot-win10-from-samsung-950-pro-nvme-on-superserver for one example. From what I can see, a lot of BIOS changes may be needed. Do go through and see how you go.